# Unity Moq not found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, moq

My Unity project contains the Moq dll, which we use for unit testing. I'm upgrading the project from Unity 2018 to 2019, and when I performed the upgrade it randomly decided Moq doesn't exist anymore. Moq is still inside the Assets folder (specifically in Assets/Plugins/dlls) and the version is defined in packages.config.

I've deleted and re-added, re-imported, and reloaded Unity multiple times to no avail. Does anyone have insight on why Unity just decided Moq doesn't exist anymore?

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same issue, upgrading from 2018 to 2019 changed how asmdef files work so you'll need to go add the dll to the asmdef under Assembly References. Leaving this answer up since I didn't find this anywhere myself.